# Zend Framework Multi Language Integration Steps

Tags: zend-framework2

I am new to **zend framework2** and I am working on a site with multi language integration. Please give me the idea about, how the builtin library and translation file should be configured, and how its can be called from view file

Answer (score 13):

ZF2 has already integrated I18n tools.

## How to integrate it

### module.config.php

```
'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

### Files *.mo

Following previous step, create a folder and add your **en_US.mo** (for example) using [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net) (simple and good application)

### Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    $translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
    $translator
      ->setLocale(\Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']))
      ->setFallbackLocale('en_US');
}
```

rq: Personally I use a session to stock my locale but it depends if I need a SEO using language

```
    // session container
    $sessionContainer = new Container('locale');

    // test if session language exists
    if(!$sessionContainer->offsetExists('mylocale')){
        // if not use the browser locale
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])){
            $sessionContainer->offsetSet('mylocale', Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']));
        }else{
            $sessionContainer->offsetSet('mylocale', 'en_US');
        }

    }

    // translating system
    $translator = $serviceManager->get('translator');
    $translator ->setLocale($sessionContainer->mylocale)
                ->setFallbackLocale('en_US');

    $mylocale = $sessionContainer->mylocale;
```

## How to use it

In a view, just type that:

```
 <?php echo $this->translate("Translate that!"); ?>
```

## Some links to explore

- http://samminds.com/2012/09/zend-framework-2-translate-i18n-locale/
- http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.i18n.translating.html
- http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/styling-and-translations.html

Comment: I got it.. Thanks Remi. Really nice explanation.

Comment: In my case I had to define the translator as an invokable service in the module.config.php. Otherwise it would not find the service.

Comment: What if I don't want the value to be set using `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` but from the `url` like `domain.com/en/...`. The route will give me value as `en` and not `en_US` which is required in ZF2. Actually I need it for `fr` which has 2 variations.